# C# covariance structure understanding?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, covariance

- Assuming

  class A
      {  }

  class B : A
      { }

covariance is not supported for generic class.

Meaning  - we cant do something like this :

```
MyConverter<B> x1= new MyConverter<B>();
MyConverter<A> x2= x1;
```

Thats fine and understood.

From my reading - i understand that Covariance will be available:

*"If you use a backing Generic Interface  Being implemented on a Generic Class  - so that access to the T type object instance  will be available through those interfaces ".*

I have just one problem.

Ive seen many examples of the "converter" class as a form of `Stack` .

But never understood " what if I want to use only 1 instance of B from a reference of A ? "

so Ive tried some code :

> Create `B` object + values  ---> use Generic Converter for `B` --->
>   use the covariance flow to get its `A` reference ---> now you can use it 
>   either as A or as B.

[image]

[image]

**My question :**

*Is That the correct way of doing this ( for using covariance for 1 object only ) ?*

p.s.
The code is working and compiled ok. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ6QO.png

Ive been asking /reading a lot about this topic lately - I dive into things in order to understand them the best I can.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code compiles and works, so is it "correct"? I guess it is!

However it is not very interesting having a stack that only contains a single element; that's not really a stack. Let's think about how you might make a truly covariant and contravariant stack.

```
interface IPush<in T> { void Push(T item); }
interface IPop<out T> { T Pop(); }
class Stack<T> : IPush<T>, IPop<T>
{
    private class Link
    {
        public T Item { get; private set; }
        public Link Next { get; private set; }
        public Link(T item, Link next) { this.Item = item; this.Next = next; }
    }

    private Link head;
    public Stack() { this.head = null; }

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        this.head = new Link(item, this.head);
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        if (this.head == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        T value = this.head.Item;
        this.head = this.head.Next;
        return value;
    }
}
```

And now you can use the stack covariantly for popping, and contravariantly for pushing:

```
Stack<Mammal> mammals = new Stack<Mammal>();
IPop<Animal> animals = mammals;
IPush<Giraffe> giraffes = mammals;
IPush<Tiger> tigers = mammals;
giraffes.Push(new Giraffe());
tigers.Push(new Tiger());
System.Console.WriteLine(animals.Pop()); // Tiger
System.Console.WriteLine(animals.Pop()); // Giraffe
```

> What if I want to use only one instance of B from a reference of A?

Your question is "what if I want to use a Tiger but I have a reference an Animal?" The answer is "you can't" because the Animal might not be a Tiger! If you want to test whether the reference to Animal is really a tiger then say:

```
Tiger tiger = myAnimal as Tiger;
if (tiger != null) ...
```

or

```
if (myAnimal is Tiger) ...
```

> What about if you want to convert class `C<B>` to `C<A>`?

That's not possible. There is no reference conversion there. The only covariant and contravariant reference conversions in C# 4 are on generic *interfaces* and generic *delegates* that are *constructed with reference types as the type arguments.* Generic classes and structs may not be used covariantly or contravariantly. The best thing you can do is make the class *implement a variant interface*.

Comment: Hi :) Thats exactly the problem that all of the examples out there ( most) are of stack. Tahts why Ive wrote `what if I want to use only 1 instance of B from a reference of A ?` Can you please refer to this situation ? Not in all situations I need stack... somwtimes i need just a single conversion of only 1 element ...?.....(p.s. thats why I Called the class `Myconverter` and Not `MySingleStack`)

Comment: I don't think a generic conversion class is the right approach to handle casting.  Want to convert `B` to `A`? Use `B as A` or `(A) B`.

Comment: @Brian It is not related. What about if you want to convert Generic Class of Type <B> to be converted to Type<A> ( in reference) ...? thats all what covariant is about to solve.... not regular casting as you wrote......

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, but if the Generic Class of Type <B> is only ever holding 1 type, you probably won't need covariant.

Comment: @eric Thank you very much. I feel that `myconverter` is kind of a bucket which holds an object which access his T object by many interfaces... and that bucket  thing is a bit unclear....(why do i need to create a bucket , put an apple in it, and later access this apple in the eyes of an interface....? **why do i need this bucket** ?) and if i have to  - so its **like a stack** with 1 item container - as my example....is that correct?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: OK, let's think about a bucket. A bucket *of what*?  A bucket that can *only hold apples* cannot be used as *a bucket of fruit*, because you can put an orange into a *bucket of fruit* but not into a *bucket of apples*. A bucket of fruit cannot be used as *a bucket that can only hold apples*, because *there might be an orange in that bucket of fruit*.

Comment: @EricLippert So from your explanation  this bucket is a FRUIT backet....., Again ( and as always) thank you very much for your wide explained answers . I wish I had a knowledge as you have.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Your wish is easily achieved. Carefully study the design and implementation of a language and its compiler for eight hours a day, five days a week, 48 weeks a year, for five to ten years and you too can have a decent knowledge of any programming language you choose. That's all it takes.

Comment: @EricLippert If I have a method `void Wash<T>(Stack<T> animals) where T : Animal {}`, why does it compile when I pass in `new Stack<Bear>()` to the method given generic class is not supported by co-variance? Of course `Animal` is the base class of `Bear` here.

Comment: @stt106: Type inference will infer that you meant to call `Wash<Bear>(Stack<Bear>)`, and `Bear` matches the constraint: `Bear` is a subtype of `Animal`.  There's no generic variance there.  You're never trying to use a stack of bears as a stack of animals. You're trying to parameterize a method that is parameterizable by any animal type with the bear type.

Comment: @EricLippert That makes sense as after it compiles it still maintains type-safety by preventing you from converting a stack of bears into a stack of animals, which would have been possible had generic class supports covariance. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the converter simply to get a reference of type `A` pointing to an object of type `B`.  There's a much easier way to do that, called casting:

```
B b = new B();
A a = (A)b;
```

In fact, since A is a superclass of B, the conversion is implicit:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
```

Your program could be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B { b1 = 22222 };
        A a = b;
        Console.WriteLine(a.a1);
        Console.WriteLine(((B)a).b1);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but the whole sample was to show how can we solve / overcome the problem with  type saftey with generic classes via generic interfaces...

Comment: But using covariance is no more nor less type safe than this.  Covariance says that if B is a subtype of A, then X<B> is a subtype of X<A>.  To get from A to B you need to downcast; to get from X<A> to X<B> you need to downcast.

Comment: Ok but you can do it with generic lists ! you cant make `list<animals> a =... list<bears>;` without generic interfaces with in or out. you have to make a middle class which will implements those generic interfaces...

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you are getting at now.

Answer (score 0):

```
IPushable<B> x1 = new MyConverter<B>();
x1.Set(b);
// I believe this is valid.
IPoppable<A> final = x2;
```

You can find some great examples and descriptions of it on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

Comment: The code is valid and compiled. pelase see the results after the Console.WriteLine... http://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ6QO.png

Comment: Hmm.  I don't quite understand that, but I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is, then?  "problematically correct" isn't really meaningful.

Comment: @zenxer. this is **not** contravariance . its Covariance . covariance is : **assumly B inherits A, so Type X is covariance if X<B> allow reference to X<A>**

Comment: Sorry, @RoyiNamir; I just didn't understand your question.  I'll leave my answer here (edited) because of the great link.